# A color drop down selector for pyqt5

Tags: python, colors, pyqt5

I've been lookin for a simple drop down box where the user can select predefined colors (for PyQt5). Of course there is the [QColorDialog](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcolordialog.html), but that clearly is not a simple drop down thingy for selecting predefined colors.
There are many questions/answers dealing with defining background colors for items in a QComboBox, but it is never a QComboBox as color selector.

So the question is:
is there a ready-at-hand (drop-down) widget that lets the user select some color, or do I have to build my own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so I came up with my own widget, based on a `QComboBox`:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QComboBox
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor

class QColorComboBox(QComboBox):
    ''' A drop down menu for selecting colors '''

    # signal emitted if a color has been selected
    selectedColor = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QColor)

    def __init__(self, parent = None, enableUserDefColors = True):
        ''' if the user shall not be able to define colors on its own, then set enableUserDefColors=False '''
        # init QComboBox
        super(QColorComboBox, self).__init__(parent)

        # enable the line edit to display the currently selected color
        self.setEditable(True)
        # read only so that there is no blinking cursor or sth editable
        self.lineEdit().setReadOnly(True)

        # text that shall be displayed for the option to pop up the QColorDialog for user defined colors
        self._userDefEntryText = 'Custom'
        # add the option for user defined colors
        if (enableUserDefColors):
            self.addItem(self._userDefEntryText)

        self._currentColor = None

        self.activated.connect(self._color_selected)
        
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def addColors(self, colors):
        ''' Adds colors to the QComboBox '''
        for a_color in colors:
            # if input is not a QColor, try to make it one
            if (not (isinstance(a_color, QColor))):
                a_color = QColor(a_color)
            # avoid dublicates
            if (self.findData(a_color) == -1):
                # add the new color and set the background color of that item
                self.addItem('', userData = a_color)
                self.setItemData(self.count()-1, QColor(a_color), Qt.BackgroundRole)
            
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def addColor(self, color):
        ''' Adds the color to the QComboBox '''
        self.addColors([color])

    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def setColor(self, color):
        ''' Adds the color to the QComboBox and selects it'''
        self.addColor(color)
        self._color_selected(self.findData(color), False)

    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def getCurrentColor(self):
        ''' Returns the currently selected QColor
            Returns None if non has been selected yet
        '''
        return self._currentColor

    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def _color_selected(self, index, emitSignal = True):
        ''' Processes the selection of the QComboBox '''
        # if a color is selected, emit the selectedColor signal
        if (self.itemText(index) == ''):            
            self._currentColor = self.itemData(index)
            if (emitSignal):
                self.selectedColor.emit(self._currentColor)
                
        # if the user wants to define a custom color
        elif(self.itemText(index) == self._userDefEntryText):
            # get the user defined color
            new_color = QColorDialog.getColor(self._currentColor if self._currentColor else Qt.white)
            if (new_color.isValid()):
                # add the color to the QComboBox and emit the signal
                self.addColor(new_color)
                self._currentColor = new_color
                if (emitSignal):
                    self.selectedColor.emit(self._currentColor)
        
        # make sure that current color is displayed
        if (self._currentColor):
            self.setCurrentIndex(self.findData(self._currentColor))
            self.lineEdit().setStyleSheet("background-color: "+self._currentColor.name())
```